# Transport pass for 5 days in Paris including 3 days in Villepinte

Tags: public-transport, tickets, paris

I will be arriving into Orly on October 18 and staying by the Latin quarter. I will then have to travel to and from Parc des expositions in Villepinte for three days (19, 20 and 21 October).

Will a Paris Visite ticket (zones 1-5) for 5 days save me money?

Comment: Did you try looking up the prices on [RATP](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/r_61584/tickets/) and comparing the costs?

Comment: Depends. Are you going for tourism? What all places do you want to visit?

Comment: Which Parc des Expositions? Porte de Versailles?

Answer (score 3):

The *Parc des expositions* near the *porte de Versailles* is served by the *métro*, so you can go there with a zone 1 ticket. Most tourists attractions would be in zone 1 too. Except if you planned something else, you only really need to get out of zone 1 to go to Versailles or to the airport.

Even assuming a round-trip to Versailles and a trip to and from the airport, the Paris Visite ticket is probably more expensive but not by much. If you don't need those, it's not interesting at all. On the plus side, it means that you wouldn't have to worry about tickets at all.

To fix ideas:

- A single trip ticket for Paris itself, if you buy them by *carnet* of 10 is EUR 1.37. These tickets would cover the way from your hotel to the *porte de Versailles* or between those and the main sights in the center.
- A one-way trip to Versailles is EUR 4.00
- A trip to Orly with Orly bus is EUR 7.50 and with OrlyVal EUR 11.65

So three short trips a day + two airport transfers + round trip to Versailles would still be under the EUR 65.50 of the 5 days/5 zone Paris Visite ticket. If you travel much more than that, you could also consider [day tickets](http://www.ratp.fr/fr/ratp/c_21148/mobilis/) and buy the tickets to the airport separately (that's the only difference between Paris Visit and the rest, but you don't need to go to the airport every day…)

Comment: The answer assumes that "parc des expositions" means Porte de Versailles. There's another "parc des expositions" located in Villepinte, which is in zone 4.

Comment: @user13619 Not at all, in fact I wrote “The Parc des expositions near the porte de Versailles” specifically because there are others (if I assumed it was the only one, I would simply write “The Parc des expositions”). You will note I commented on the issue above, long before anyone else raised it.

Comment: sorry if you felt this comment was inappropriate. My only goal was to raise OP's attention on the ambiguity of "parc des expositions".

Comment: @user13619 I think the OP does not get notified when you comment an answer (instead of the question itself).

Answer (score 2):

Paris Visite is mostly a tourist trap. It only comes in zones 1–3 or zones 1–5, while all major tourist attractions are in zone 1 except for the Versailles Palace which is in zone 4, and Orly airport is in zone 4, Roissy airport is in zone 5, so most tourists will want the more expensive zones 1–5 pass. The *Parc des Expositions* in Villepinte is in zone 4, the one at Porte de Versailles is in zone 1.

The current [price](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/r_61634/paris-visite/) is 22.85€ for 1 day, with decreasing daily rates down to 59.50€ for 5 days. This is rarely worth it if you're using it for transport alone, only if you're interested in the meager [discounts](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/r_107634/partenaires-paris-visite-2014/).

A [day ticket](http://www.ratp.fr/fr/ratp/c_21148/mobilis/) for zones 1–4 costs 11.20€, and is not valid to travel from or to the airports. It won't be useful for you, it's only worth the price if you make at last three cross-zone trips or have bus connections. A [weekly ticket](http://www.ratp.fr/fr/ratp/c_21137/forfaits-navigo-mois-et-semaine/) for zones 1–4 costs 37€ (including the 5€ cost to buy the reusable physical token), but this only runs Monday to Sunday, so it isn't applicable to you.

A single ticket between Paris and the Parc des expositions in Villepinte costs 4.20€. A ticket for the Orlybus service costs 7.50€. A ticket to the station serving the Versailles Palace costs 4.20€. That's 48.6€ plus a few tickets within Paris: 1.70€ for a single ticket, 13.70€ for a book of 10.

So for you, if you go to Villepinte three times and visit the Versailles Palace and move around a little in Paris, a Paris Visite pass is the cheapest pass. If you don't go to Versailles and stay put in Paris then the Paris Visite pass is more expensive, but only slightly. If you're going to the Parc des expositions near Porte de Versailles and not the one in Paris, get a book of “ticket t+” (valid for one Paris metro trip or one bus/tram trip with bus/tram connections) and single tickets for the airport (and Versailles if you want to go there).

Comment: I will be going to Parc des expositions in Villepinte for three days and returning back to Paris @Gilles